# Angular Ivy type check: Type 'SafeHtml' is not assignable to type 'string'

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-ivy

I am getting **Typescript error** after switching to *Ivy compiler*:

```sh
[Step 4/5] src/app/app.component.html(1,26): Type 'SafeHtml' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

In Angular class there is a member property declared as `SafeHtml`:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  template: `<div [innerHTML]="description"></div>`
})
export class AppComponent {
  description: SafeHtml;

  constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.description = this.sanitizer.sanitize(SecurityContext.HTML, '<strong>whatever comes from server</strong>');
  }
}
```

My question is how to convert `SafeHtml` and `SafeUrl` to string? Is it just `.toString()` OK?

Angulars `SafeHtml` is declared as:

```js
/**
 * Marker interface for a value that's safe to use as HTML.
 *
 * @publicApi
 */
export declare interface SafeHtml extends SafeValue {
}
```

And [innerHtml] defined in lib.dom.d.ts:

```js
interface InnerHTML {
    innerHTML: string;
}
```

The `innerHtml` is type of `string`, whereas I have `SafeHtml`.

How to reproduce:

```sh
git clone https://github.com/felikf/angular-repro-safe-html.git
npm i
npm run build
```

[image]

Comment: Could you please provide your actual code, and not the one you think is relevant ? Typescript typing errors come from the TS, not the template : the code you have provided is next to useless to help you ...

Comment: I think you are wrong - Angular Ivy compiler does stricter typechecking on Angular templates. As mentioned in this article: https://blog.angularindepth.com/type-checking-templates-in-angular-viewengine-and-ivy-77f8536359f5  My issue is, that description is defined as `SafeHtml` whereas `InnerHtml` is defined as `String` in lib.dom.d.ts.

Comment: Sure, whatever you want. But unless you provide the code, no-one will be able to help you out.

Comment: (Also, as per [ask], you should provide a [mcve], so I guess more code isn't that bad after all !)

Comment: @Maryannah you are right. I have added steps to reproduce the issue - please see the question.

Comment: Is that error coming from a serve command, or a build command ?

Comment: Is it comming from `npm run build`.

Comment: Ok, either try `description: SafeHtml | string;` or `description: any;` to see ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200510/discussion-between-felix-and-maryannah).

Comment: I had the same issue and the fix was "SafeHtml | string" as mentioned by user467 ... although I wonder if it was a fix or a hack?  The latter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be a bug, for now this is the answer: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/33028